# Change the date from local time to UTC with weird format

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to convert a time&date string from the local time to UTC.
Here is what I have :

I use fullcalendar, and when the user clicks a date it will trigger a modal and in the modal, there is a field for the user to pick a date
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R0dV.png)

For example, let's say that the user wants to use that date, now I need to convert it to UTC.

```
a =$('#Date').val();
console.log(a);
"December 20, 2021"
```

```
b = $('#Time').val();
console.log(b);
"12:30 AM"
```

```
c = a + " " + b;
console.log(c);
"12:30 AMDecember 20, 2021"
```

So I need the c variable converted to utc.

Now what I am having trouble with is the format,

```
y = selectedDate = moment(c, 'h:mm DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Is not working
And I am not 100% sure how to do this correctly.

```
console.log(y.utc());
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "December 20, 2021 12:30 AM", _f: "h:mm DD/MM/YYYY", _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _d: Date Mon Dec 20 2021 20:30:00 (local time :D), _isValid: true, _ambigTime: false, _ambigZone: false, … }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) (the successor to Moment).

You can use its methods [`DateTime.fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) and [`DateTime.toUTC`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoutc) to get the data you need:

```html
<script type="module">

import {DateTime} from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@2.2.0/build/es6/luxon.js';

const dateStr = 'December 20, 2021';
const timeStr = '12:30 AM';
const dtString = `${timeStr} ${dateStr}`;

const parseFormat = 'h:mm a MMMM d, y';
const locale = 'en-US';
const dt = DateTime.fromFormat(dtString, parseFormat, {locale});

const logInfo = (name, dt) => console.log(name, dt.toString(), dt.toObject());

logInfo('local', dt);
logInfo('utc', dt.toUTC());

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your parse string is wrong. You can use `"MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A"` as the parse string. Please check the below example.

```js
const a= "December 20, 2021"
const b= "12:30 AM"
const c = `${a} ${b}`;

console.log(moment().format("MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A"))
y = selectedDate = moment(c, "MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A");

console.log(y.utc());
console.log(y.format("MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!